# Body opacity affecting whole page?

Tags: html, css

i am making a popup. I have everything done, but when i want to make the opacity of anything behind it (i use the body tag) to 0.6 , the popup's opacity is changed too. How do i make this to where everything but the popup's opacity is dropped? - Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Questions like this have been asked _so many times_. Look in the Related column to the right of this comment.

Comment: Sorry...i did not look, i was in a hurry.

Comment: Look at the source of any of the 5 billion existing Lightbox implementations to find out how it's done.

Comment: Stop exaggerating, @thirtydot.   There can't be more than 2 billion Lightbox implementations. 3 tops...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using rgba instead of opacity:

`background-color: rgba(0, 0 , 0, 0.5);`

It's: red, green, blue, alpha transparency values

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was curious about this question and found out somewhere in Stack Overflow that a child element can never have opacity higher than its parent, nor override it (not an "official" source but I believe it).

So, the best workaround I saw is put your popup outside the low opacity element. Since it makes no sense to put the popup outside `<body>`, I wrap all the content in one div and put the popup outside. For example:

I can't show the body tags in JSFiddle but here's the link anyway http://jsfiddle.net/qWRj5/1/

```
<body>
<div id="all">Lorem Ipsun Delores Sic Transit Glori Repium Sider Traministu 
Difirenziatum Tiramisu. Lorem Ipsun Delores Sic Transit Glori Repium Sider Traministu 
Difirenziatum Tiramisu. Lorem Ipsun Delores Sic Transit Glori Repium Sider Traministu 
Difirenziatum Tiramisu. 
</div>

<div id="popup">My Gosh, that is some awful Latin</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#all { opacity: 0.5 }
#popup { padding: 10px; border: 2px dotted blue; position: absolute; left: 20px; 
  top: 10px; background-color: #fce; }
```

​

Comment: The usual way to do it looks more like `<body>content of page
<div id="overlay" style="background:#000;opacity:0.5;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0"></div>
<div id="popup" style="background:#fff;position:absolute">Popup here</div></body>`.

Comment: There was something wrong with one of the `</div>`, I get the same problem when I directly copy and paste the HTML I wrote. How strange. Here's a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/q7Smn/2/.

Comment: It's Stack Overflow inserting `U+200C` and `U+200B` to [force comments to wrap](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91498/is-there-a-css-problem-on-stackoverflow/91512#91512). Note to self: never put long HTML in Stack Overflow comments.